# Is it possible to enable session state for authenticated users only in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, session-state

MVC3 added a good opportunity to make sessionless controllers using `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]` attribute. That's great but not flexible because you cannot set session state for each controller method and also you cannot enable it by condition.

Is it possible to enable session state for authenticated users only or by some other custom condition?
I.e. PHP has a great feature.
`if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();`
That would be nice to find something like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could override the default controller factory and more specifically the [GetControllerSessionBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.icontrollerfactory.getcontrollersessionbehavior.aspx) method:

```
public class MyControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override SessionStateBehavior GetControllerSessionBehavior(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            return SessionStateBehavior.Default;
        }

        if (requestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // enable session if there's an authenticated user
            return SessionStateBehavior.Required;
        }

        return SessionStateBehavior.Disabled;
    }
}
```

and in `Application_Start` replace the default controller factory with the custom one:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyControllerFactory());
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!
I'm also going to extend that to allow using attribute for each controller method (in case if you need to use TempData for anonymous users). I don't know if it is possible to get the executing method name from `RequestContext`

Comment: Yes, I did it. If somebody is interested in **disabling Session State per Controller Method** ask me here and I'll share my solution!

Comment: @Cheburek .. Can you please share your solution with me?

Comment: @alok_dida  Please see below.

Answer (score 2):

How to **disable Session State per Controller Method**.
It works properly even for such flow:

1. request method with enabled session
2. request method with disabled session
3. request method with enabled session - values preserved (I don't understand why but it is so)

   ```
     /// <summary>
     /// Enable session if there's an authenticated user or method in controller is marked with <see cref="SessionAttribute" /> or controller class is marked within <see cref="SessionAttribute" /> or <see cref="SessionStateAttribute" />
     /// </summary>
     public class AuthSessionControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
     {

       protected override SessionStateBehavior GetControllerSessionBehavior(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
       {
         if ( controllerType == null ) return SessionStateBehavior.Default;

         return requestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
           ? SessionStateBehavior.Required
           : GetDefaultSessionBehavior( requestContext, controllerType );
       }

    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, SessionStateBehavior> _sessionStateCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SessionStateBehavior>();
    protected SessionStateBehavior GetDefaultSessionBehavior(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
     if ( !requestContext.RouteData.Values.Keys.Contains( "action" ) ) return SessionStateBehavior.Required;
     var act = requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

     return _sessionStateCache.GetOrAdd( controllerType + act,
       (type => {
         var typeCopy = controllerType;

         //get current action
         var methods = typeCopy.GetMethods().Where( m => m.Name == act ).ToArray();
         foreach (var method in methods) {

           //look for SessionAttribute on the method
           var attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute( method, typeof( SessionAttribute ), false );
           if ( attr != null ) return (( SessionAttribute )attr).Behavior;


           //support default SessionState behavior
           var controllerattr = typeCopy.GetCustomAttributes( typeof( SessionStateAttribute ), true )
             .OfType<SessionStateAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
           if ( controllerattr == null ) 
           {
             var controllerattrCustom = typeCopy.GetCustomAttributes( typeof( SessionAttribute ), true )
               .OfType<SessionAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
             if ( controllerattrCustom != null ) return controllerattrCustom.Behavior;
           } else
             return controllerattr.Behavior;
         }
         return SessionStateBehavior.Disabled;

       }) );
   }
   ```

   }

Register it in `Application_Start()` method in Global.asax

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory( new AuthUserSessionControllerFactory() );
```

Here is a SessionAttribute class - it looks like SessionStateAttribute from MS - the only difference is that this one is allowed for Methods

```
[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true )]
  public sealed class SessionAttribute : Attribute
  {

    public SessionAttribute(SessionStateBehavior behavior)
    {
      Behavior = behavior;
    }

    public SessionStateBehavior Behavior { get; private set; }
  }
```